# Django объект модели не привязывается к профилю

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Я только учу Django и пытаюсь создать некий клон Инстаграм.
Моя проблема заключается в том что при создании поста он не привязывается к модели Profile.

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/pictures', default='static/images/default-profile.png', null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
                 update_fields=None):
            super().save()

            img = Image.open(self.profile_pic.path)
            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.profile_pic.path)
```

**posts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Profile
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    post_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos', null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} by @{}".format(self.post_title, self.profile)
```

**posts/fomrs.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *


class CreatePostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fileds = '__all__'
        exclude = ['profile', 'date_created']
```

**posts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createPost(request):
    form = CreatePostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

И вот при создании поста уже с самого сайта можно увидеть что в админ панели поле Profile пустое.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поидее достаточно добавить профайл перед сохранением, сначала делаем
`post = form.save(commit=False)` - создаем инстанс поста, но не сохраняем его в базу, далее прикрепляем к нему profile
`post.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)`
и сохраняем пост в бд. В итоге должно получиться так:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createPost(request):
    form = CreatePostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            post.save()
            return redirect('profile')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```